# Other apps gets the message before my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-ndk

In my application, after receiving a specific message i do some task. It works well but when some other sms applications like HookUp(in micromax) and go sms pro is installed in device, these application also gets the message. I have set highest priority to my application. I want to stop bypassing the sms to these application. Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have set highest priority to my application receiver i.e. 2147483647

Comment: I have done with the instructions given at below link - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/159017 . But some other apps may also set the highest priority to their listener, So they also gets the same message, I want to stop them But dont know how?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stop them But dont know how?

Ask the user to uninstall those apps.

My guess is that the tiebreaker for `BroadcastReceivers` registered at the same priority is installation order. That seems to be the behavior, based on described behavior in these StackOverflow questions. Hence, if these other apps were installed before yours, they will get the broadcasts first, and there is nothing that you can do about it.

If the user values your application enough, they will uninstall those other apps (which definitely gives you priority), perhaps reinstalling them later (which may give you priority).

Comment: I checked with this, I installed go sms pro after my application but it still gets the message and shows pop up.

Comment: Is your service and the ones from other apps started on phone boot or manually ?